# Changing input type hidden to text when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, input, checkbox

I was just wondering what is the best way to change the type of input from hidden to text when a checkbox button is checked.

I am looking for something like this

```
   <div class="options">
     <input type="checkbox" checked="">
   </div>

    <form>
        <input type="hidden">
    </form>
```

and then one the checkbox is checked

```
   <div class="options">
     <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   </div>

    <form>
        <input type="text">
    </form>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp
check out the "set attributes"

Comment: Please post an example of the code you've tried, and whenever possible an example at jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it this way, for fun:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txt").toggle();
    $("#chk").change(function () {
        $("#txt").toggle();
    });
});

<input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```

Instead of changing it from hidden to text, I'd just toggle the visibility of a single input element. This of course starts of hidden and becomes visible of you check, invisible if you uncheck. If you want different behavior you'll have some minor work to do, but I'm sure you're smart enough to handle it.

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [**this live jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BTGSk/)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check1">Show checkbox</input>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden1" value="Some Value" />
<input type="text" class="text1" style="display:none" />
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".check1").click(function () {
    if ($('.check1').is(':checked')) {
        $(".text1").val($(".hidden1").val());
        $(".text1").show();
    } else {
        $(".text1").val("");
        $(".text1").hide();
    }
});
```

---

Based on the code you posted, this is what you are looking for:

```
$('.options input[type='checkbox']').click(function () {
    if ($('.options input[type='checkbox']').is(':checked')) {
        $('form').html("<input type='text'>");
    } else {
        $('form').html("<input type='hidden'>");
    }
});
```

I'm not use why you wanna do that, though. Are you just trying to show and hide the textbox? In that case, you can just write:

```
$('.options input[type='checkbox']').click(function () {
    $('input[type='text']').toggle();
});
```